# Listing of functions in java

Tags: java

am new to the java world and am having troubles in remembering the function names in various imports. So is there a way to open an import file and see all functions within it ?
basically what I need is the syntax.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)?

Comment: What you need is documentation. Google it.

Comment: To begin with, Java doesn't have functions but methods. Secondly, use an IDE with auto complete functionality that will help you to, uhm, auto complete some methods and will even tell you the parameters they need. Third, read the javadoc of the Java classes you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanielGibbs stated, the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) should be bookmarked so you can have it handy when you have a question.

But also if you use an IDE like [IntelliJIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/java.php), you should also be able to find the Javadoc through some means like hovering over a class/method or with a Control-Click.

Answer (score 4):

The [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is probably what you're looking for.
The frame on the left lists all the classes, and when you select one the main frame will list all of the functions, their parameters, and return values.